# Can someone help me understand this JavaScript code

Tags: javascript

This code is used to add new books but I don't understand how it really works. I'm seeing a variable books used but was never assigned. How did it come to existence?

```
        <script>
            const bookManager = {
                addBook: function(book){
                    if(!this.books){
                        this.books = [book];
                    } else{
                        this.books.push(book);
                    }
                }
            };
        </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bookManager` is an object. `addBook`  is a method inside the object. The `addBook` method when called is checking if the bookManager object have a property called `books`. If it does not have the `books` then it is creating a `books` property in this line  `this.books = [book];` and adding `book` to it. If it has the property then it is pushing the `book` to it. Here `this` representing the object `bookManager`

```js
const bookManager = {
  addBook: function(book) {
    if (!this.books) {
      this.books = [book];
    } else {
      this.books.push(book);
    }
  }
};

bookManager.addBook('test');
console.log(bookManager.books)
```

Answer (score 0):

`this.books` is initialized if it does not exist at: `this.books=[book]`. The check if it is empty is done in the if statement at: `if(!this.books){}`. It will be falsy the first time. If it exists, the next `book` will be pushed into the new array.

Comment: I understand it now

Comment: @Robert-JanKuyper "The check if it is empty ..." not empty, but rather "undefined", "null" or "falsy"

Answer (score 0):

The Manager object takes 'book' as argument and adds it to an array which is a property (similar to 'members' in other object-oriented languages). If the array doesn't exist, it creates one and initializes it with 'book' as the first element.

The usage would be

```
bookManager.addBook("The Swarm")
```

Result:

```
console.log(bookManager.books)

Array(1)
["The Swarm"]
```

Answer (score 0):

`bookManager` is an object that contains a function called `addBook`. This function accepts a prop called `book`. `this.books` is creating a variable inside the function(`addBook`) that is only useable only in that function. There is also an if statement that adds book or books to `this.books`. If *this.books* is `false` then *this.books* will be an array of the given prop(`book`), and if *this.books* is `true`, then it will add the book to the *this.books*. Later, you can access the *this.books* that `this` is referring to the *object name* which is `bookManager`.

```js
const bookManager = {
  addBook: function(book) {
    if (!this.books) {
      this.books = [book];
    } else {
      this.books.push(book);
    }
  }
};

bookManager.addBook('Harry Potter');
console.log(bookManager.books);
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's Check it step by step:

first you have a javascript object named bookManager.

```
const bookManager = {}
```

inside the object you have a function called `addBook` which takes `book` as a parameter.

inside the function, existence of this.books which `this` refers to `addBook` function is checked. in this code it's always going to be false so the code inside  `if (!this.books) {}`

will always run and would assign an array with initial value of `book` to `this.books`. in this code example the `else` block would never run but if you modify your code to have `this.books` initialized early, like this :

```
const bookManager = {
    addBook: function (book) {
        this.books = ['testi']
        if (!this.books) {
            this.books = [book];
        } else {
            this.books.push(book);
        }
    }
};

bookManager.addBook('tast');

console.log(bookManager.books)
```

then the `else` block would run instead of `if` block and as now there already is a `this.books`, new book would be pushed with `Array.push()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Basically how this works step by step:
First, we define the variable `bookManager` which is an object.

```js
const bookManager = {}
```

Inside of the definition line there is this code:

```js
const bookManager = {
    addBook: function (book) {
        if (!this.books) {
            this.books = [book];
        } else {
            this.books.push(book);
        }
    },
};
```

Inside of the bookManager object we have an `addBook` function. Inside of the `addBook` function we can see that it basically does two things:

1. It checks to see if `bookManager` (`this`) has a `books` value.
2. If it does, then it uses `Array.push()` to add a new item to the end of the array (which is `book`)
3. If not, then create a new array `this.books` with the first item being the parameter `book`.

Now you've noticed that there is now a new variable `bookManager.books` in the `bookManager` object. This is because when in the function we say `this` it means `bookManager` in this case. So that means that the line `this.books` means `bookManager.books`. The new variable `this.books` gets added to the bookManager object.

Now, to test this we can run the following code:

```js
bookManager.addBook("hello, world");
console.log(bookManager.books);
```

In the console an array with the only item being `"hello, world"` will be logged.